# convert 32 bit, binary number to decimal in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to convert a 32-bit number to decimal in python. I'm quite new at python and so I'm not sure how to go about it. What I have so far is something like

```
file=open('filepath', 'rb')
num=file.read(4)
```

The value for num looks something like

```
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00'
```

How can I easily convert this to an integer value that can be stored? Eventually I will want to read in every value of this file, and store them to plotted later.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect as the integer output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a module called struct which might be helpful when unpacking bytes to integer or any other form.

```
import struct
struct.unpack('i', b'\x05\x00\x00\x00') # i stands for integer
```

Gives output as `(5,)` which you can again unpack in some var or use it directly as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks Jay! The unpack method does work. I do have a followup then. I'm trying to fill an array with this data and it is showing up in the array as ((5,),(24,),(10,),...) Do you know how to store them as just (5,24,10,...)?

Comment: When you append the data in the array, use your_list.append(val[0]). This will extract the first (and only) value from the tuples and it'll be stored in your list.